# Use ">" (greater than) as a cell reference in IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I would like to use the ">" operator as a cell reference.

I know it is possible with the COUNTIF function. For example, if the A1 cell contains ">", I can use the formula COUTIF(range, A1 & 2) to get the number of cells greater than 2 in the range.

But here I want to do the same with the IF function (in a condition). So say the B1 cell contains a certain number, do something like IF(B1 & A1 & 2, do x) which would do x if B1 is greater than 2.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is "no", but you could use countif with a single-cell range like =IF(COUNTIF(B1,A1&2),10,20)

Answer (score 1):

Could do if statement on the symbol in A1 where column B is your data, the nested if statement in cell c1 would be:

`=IF(IF(A1=">",TRUE,FALSE),IF(B1>2, "b1 greater than 2 condition","b1 less than 2 condition"),"not > symbol")`

Comment: I like it thanks!